# What is the difference between `SemanticGraph` and `Tree` in Stanford NLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

What is the difference between `SemanticGraph` and `Tree`, say `TreeGraphNode` in Stanford NLP?

Answer (score 0):

`SemanticGraph` is a [dependency tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree#Dependency-based_parse_trees), whereas `Tree` is a [constituency tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree#Constituency-based_parse_trees). That is, the first is a structure like `cat <-nsubj- eats -dobj-> fish`. The second is a structure like `(S (NP (NN cat)) (VP (VBZ eats) (NP (NN fish))))`.